# Terraform external json file template fill list

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I am creating a step function using terraform.

The step function is a json file.

Currently, I am using following approach, here `var.my_subnets` is a array.

```
data "template_file" "pipeline_step_fn_definition" {
  template = file("pipeline_step_fn_definition.json")
  vars = {
    ecs_container_subnets = var.my_subnets
  }
}
```

`pipeline_step_fn_definition.json`

```json
{
    "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
    "StartAt": "Pipeline",
    "States": {
        "Run Pipeline": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "TaskDefinition": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "NetworkConfiguration": {
                    "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                        "AssignPublicIp": "DISABLED",
                        "Subnets": [
                            ?????
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I pass list `var.my_subnets` to `"Subnet"` value in the JSON? For passing simple string works as expected but I am not able to pass list.

Another approach will be to use `templatefile`. The problem in the second approach is `pipeline_step_fn_definition.json` will no longer will be json. It will become something like this

```json
{
    "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
    "StartAt": "Pipeline",
    "States": {
        "Run Pipeline": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "TaskDefinition": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "NetworkConfiguration": {
                    "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                        "AssignPublicIp": "DISABLED",
                        "Subnets": [for subnet in subnets : "${subnet}"]
                    }
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

And now I can use `jsonencode` to get my formatted JSON.

The problem with this approach is my JSON file is no longer a valid JSON, it's a template and my linters will not be lining the file.

Can I do something in first approach to pass the list ?

or

Can I do something in second approach without breaking the json file to have benefits of linting ?

Comment: No you can't. You have to add TF code to your json to make it property work with template data.